# Exception in template helper: Error: Can't use $ on component with no DOM

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a note-taking application in Meteor. I have a live-preview which updates as you type that shows what the note would look like after submitting it, it also renders the markdown. Now I want to add syntax highlighting to the preview note.

If what I'm trying to do is not completely clear to you, check out the [demo here](http://brainstorm-notes.meteor.com/). And try creating a new note. Inside the preview, I'd like to add syntax highlighting.

Since the live-preview needs to rerun the syntax-highlighting every time something gets typed, I need a way to hook into a rerender of the content of the preview-note, to rerun the highlightjs code.

With previous versions of Meteor, this was very simple by simply using `Template.render = function () {...}`. But that's not possible anymore, since the API changed to only run render once, when the template renders for the first time.

What I want to try now is the following. Add a template helper next to the markdown render function, so it'll run every time the content gets updated. In this `rerender` function, I'll look up the current template instance, and run the highlighting code.

### Template

```
<template name="previewNote">
{{#if content}}
<div class="note preview">
    <h2 class="previewTitle">Preview</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="middleNote">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <!-- THIS LINE -->
        <p class='note-content'>{{#markdown}}{{content}}{{rerender}}{{/markdown}}</p>
        <!-- THIS LINE -->
    </div>
    <hr>
    <ul class="tags bottomNote">
        {{#each tags}}
        <li class="tag"><a>{{this}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

### JS

```
Template.previewNote.rerender = function () {
    // get the current template instance, and highlight all code blocks
    var codes = UI._templateInstance().findAll("pre>code");
    for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(codes[i]);
    }
};
```

This seemed pretty solid, until I tried it out and got an exception.

`Exception in template helper: Error: Can't use $ on component with no DOM`.

I'm looking for either: Why this error happens, and how I can fix it. Or another method, to achieve the result I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm running an older version of Meteor, a package is holding me back from updating, I'm not sure which one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Tracker.autorun` like this:

```
Template.previewNote.rendered = function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
      // every time Template.currentData is changed then this function reruns
      Template.currentData();

      var codes = self.findAll("pre>code");
      for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
         hljs.highlightBlock(codes[i]);
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: I saw your deleted post, and tried it out. It works perfectly when combined with a debounce, thanks!

Comment: I deleted it to create quickly example: https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/tree/master/meteor/rerun-function-templates-data-change which prooves my answer.

Comment: I'd like to thank you again, this solution is very useful in so many situations I couldn't solve before. Thanks a bunch!